# cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: message="line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'">

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

i'm trying to execute this statement but i don't know where the problem is

```
prepared = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE meal = Breakfast")
```

i'm getting this error

```
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'">
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have incorrect CQL - put Breakfast into single quotes. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/valid_literal_r.html) on how different data types must be represented.

P.S. also it’s better to prepare a query with placeholder instead of specific value (`where meal = ?`), and pass that value as parameter when executing the query - then quoting, etc. will be done automatically. See Python driver docs for examples